# Bootstrap Drop Down Menu Collapsing Before Link Can Be Clicked On Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This problem only persist in screen width less than 
990

Using the `startup framework` which is  built on `Bootstrap` I have a drop down menu in my navigation bar. It works perfectly on desktop versions of the site but on mobile versions when the drop down menu is clicked it drops shows the links then immediately collapses again. This makes it impossible to navigate the website from a mobile device.

The link to the navbar is [HERE](http://www.wuno.com/lpi/)

This is my html for my navigation

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right">
                    <ul class="nav pull-left">                                              
<?php
$pages = array(
    "home" => "HOME", 
    "about" => "ABOUT"
); 
$p = (isset($_GET['p'])) ? $_GET['p'] : "";
foreach ($pages as $url => $label) {
?>
<li><a <?= $p == $url ? 'class="active"' : ""?> href="index.php?p=<?=$url?>" > <?=$label?> </a></li>
<?php
}
?>   

 <li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">SERVICES<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <span class="dropdown-arrow"></span>   
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="engineering.php">ENGINEERING</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CERTIFICATION</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MANUFACTURING</a></li>            
                  </ul>
                </li>    

 <li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">CONTACT<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <span class="dropdown-arrow"></span>   
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
                    <li><a href="employees.php">EMPLOYMENT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="empPortal.php">EMPLOYEE PORTAL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="cust.php">CUSTOMER PORTAL</a></li>             
                  </ul>
                </li>    
                </div>    
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have moved the drop down class to the `a` tag and wrapped the drop down menu in a separate div but nothing helps. The only other thing I can think to do is to mess with the `JS`but I have no clue where to start?

Is this a known issue with bootstrap? or am I missing something in my code?

```
window.isRetina = (function() {
    var root = ( typeof exports == 'undefined' ? window : exports);
    var mediaQuery = "(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),(min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),(min-resolution: 1.5dppx)";
    if (root.devicePixelRatio > 1)
        return true;
    if (root.matchMedia && root.matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches)
        return true;
    return false;
})();

window.startupKit = window.startupKit || {};

startupKit.hideCollapseMenu = function() {
    $('body > .navbar-collapse').css({
        'z-index': 1
    });
    $('html').removeClass('nav-visible');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('body > .navbar-collapse').addClass('collapse');
        $('body > .colapsed-menu').removeClass('show-menu');
    }, 400)
}

$(function () {
    $('.page-wrapper, .navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-collapse a, .navbar-collapse button, .navbar-collapse input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e) {
        if($('html').hasClass('nav-visible')) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                startupKit.hideCollapseMenu();
            }, 200)
        }
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if($(window).width() > 965) {
            startupKit.hideCollapseMenu();
        }
    });

    var menuCollapse = $('#header-dockbar > .colapsed-menu').clone(true);
    $('body').append(menuCollapse);

    $('#open-close-menu').on('click', function () {
        if($('html').hasClass('nav-visible')) {
            startupKit.hideCollapseMenu();
        } else {
            $('body > .colapsed-menu').addClass('show-menu');
            if($('#header-dockbar').length) {
                 $('body > .colapsed-menu').css({
                    top: $('#header-dockbar').height()
                });
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('html').addClass('nav-visible');
            }, 1)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i think problem is in your css can you share that

Comment: Provide some working fiddle of it, so that we can see that and can modify it

Comment: The problems is I am using the startup framework. So I am not exactly sure how the mobile version of the nav bar is made. I was hoping someone would see this who had experience with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok after analyzing your code there are few things which attracted my attention

1. Under screen size 1000 approx your screen shifts and a white space is created
2. you used `body > .navbar-collapse .pull-right` which is wrong pull right is with nav collapse not in it.
3. your are using page-transitions.js and swipebox.js which is not used

suggestions:

1. remove unwanted js so it will not create unwanted conflicts.
2. check **.pull-right** when it is called it is the class which **is creating the collapsing problem**

EDIT: can you tell me where is this collapse function js is. I was not able to find it, if you know i can help better

EDIT2:  try changing `.navbar-collapse` a with `.navbar-collapse li:not(.dropdown)`

```
$(function () {
    $('.page-wrapper, .navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-collapse li:not(.dropdown), .navbar-collapse button, .navbar-collapse input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e) {
        if($('html').hasClass('nav-visible')) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                startupKit.hideCollapseMenu();
            }, 200)
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I fixed those js files. they were for as slideshow. I have been removing files to see if the problem still exist. I can not figure out what is collapsing the nav bar at around 1000. I dont know where to look at this point. Is there anyway I can look whent he js fires off? like when i resize the browser?

Comment: I think I found it. in startup-kit.js I find some code i think is relevant. I added it to my initial post. thanks for your help.

Comment: When I remove that js file the nav bar will collapse but it wont open when it is collapsed. I assume this is the file were looking for. Also I assume the problem is this file is conflicting with the bootstrap js. Any help would be appreciated I am very bad with JS.

Comment: I think it has a on click function that collapses the menu. So when a link is clicked the menu will collapse. I think thats whats causing the issue.

Comment: I was thinking one of the functions I showed you with my updated code. Thats somoe JS I found in the file startup-kit.js

Comment: @NDiaz i updated my answer check it if it will not work tell me

Comment: This does fix the problem on the browser but it does not fix the problem on a android mobile device.